# Limit as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ of $(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+xy^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the function 
$$f(x,y)=(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+xy^2}}$$
and I want to evaluate the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches zero.

I have started thinking of a solution but get stuck.
Taking the direct limit is not possible since that would make an undefined function. Approaching $(0,0)$ from different lines e.g $y=x$ and $y=0$ both gives hints that the limit could be $e$ but that does not really show anything. 
I tried switching to polar coordinates which gives me
$$(1+r^2)^{\frac{1}{r^2+r^3\cos(t)\sin^2(t)}}$$ 
Was it a good idea to switch to polar coordinates, can it be solved continuing with this approach, or could the function $f$ maybe be simplified and solved in a different way?

Comment: I think Polar coordinates is not a good idea for this problem.

Comment: Polar coordinates are a nice approach, but you should consider $\ln{f}$ instead.

Comment: Yes, Polar coordinates are a good idea, and you can easily compute the limit and find that it is equal to $e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just note that, as $r\to 0$,
$$(1+r^2)^{\frac{1}{r^2+r^3\cos(t)\sin^2(t)}}=\exp\left(\frac{\overbrace{\frac{\log(1+r^2)}{r^2}}^{\to 1}}{1+\underbrace{r\cos(t)\sin^2(t)}_{\to 0}}\right)\to e$$
where we used the fact that, $\log(1+r^2)=r^2+o(r^2)$ and $|r\cos(t)\sin^2(t)|\leq r$ (the bound is **independent** of $t$).

Comment: Thank you, how did you get to the equation with exp involved? I may be missing something basic but its been a while with math for me

Comment: Just use the definition of $\exp$ and $\log$: for $x>0$, we have that $x^y=\exp(\log(x^y))=\exp(y\log(x))$.

Comment: Got it. When calculating the limit after rewriting the function do you then use the chain rule ?

Comment: Yes, composition of limits.

Comment: @RobertZ Doesn't your solution only prove that the limit of $f$ along straight lines is $e$? What about other sorts of curves? For example, considering $\frac{x^2y}{1+x^4y^2}$, this function's limit is $0$ if you use polar coordinates, but it doesn't have a limit if you compute it along a parabola, for instance.

Comment: @AmitZach No, my proof shows that the limit is $e$ along any curve which goes to the origin. Note that $|r\cos(t)\sin^2(t)|\leq r\to 0$, i.e. the limit is $0$ uniformly with respect to the angle $t$ (which is necessarily fixed!!!). BTW, have you downvoted my answer? May I know why?

Comment: @AmitZach Thanks for the 5 downvotes! Maybe now you can read my comment. Do you still think that my solution only proves that the limit of $f$ along straight lines is $e$?

Comment: @RobertZ You are certainly the most annoying person I've encountered in this forum. Your solution is incorrect. It only shows the limit along straight lines. Doing **exactly** what you did on $\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$, we would get $\frac{r \cos(\theta)^2 \sin(\theta)}{r^2 \cos(\theta)^4+\sin(\theta)^2} $. The limit of this when $r \to 0$ is of course, $0$. However, on the parabola $y=x^2$ the limit is $\frac 12$. Thus, the limit **does not exist**. I'm not saying that the OP's function has no limit - I'm saying your proof is incorrect. You tagged me 5 times this week - stop harassing me

Comment: @AmitZach Again: my solution IS correct: $|r\cos(t)\sin^2(t)|\leq r\to 0$ independently on the angle $t$ which is not fixed. You can think $t=t(r)$ .  I am very sorry for your bad reaction. I am not going to disturb you anymore. Have a nice day.