# The limit of $(1+x^2+y^2)^{1\over x^2 + y^2 +xy^2}$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0.0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im having trouble solving the following limit problem:

Whats the limit of $(1+x^2+y^2)^{1\over x^2 + y^2 +xy^2}$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0.0)$.

I know that the first step is to change $(x,y)$ to polar coordinates. However after I've done that and simplified the expression I'm left with the following: 
$$
(1+r^2)^{1\over r^2+r^2\cos(α) \sin^2(α)}. 
$$
How do i prove that the expression goes to $e$ when $r→0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this $$(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+xy^2}}$$?

Comment: Yes, i'm so sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: Also, exact duplicate to [Limit as (x,y)
approaches (0,0)
of ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3284889/115115)

Comment: A suggestion: You could rewrite your equation to $(1+r^2) ^ {\frac{1}{r^2}} $ and then substitute $r^2$ with $r^2 = \frac{1}{v}$ and you get the definition of $e$.

Comment: MMA says the result is given by  $$\sqrt{e}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can write it using the limit laws, esp. the one on composition of continuous functions, as
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(1+x^2+y^2)^{1\over x^2+y^2+xy^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(1+x^2+y^2)^{1\over x^2+y^2}\right)^{x^2+y^2 \over x^2+y^2+xy^2}
\\
=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \exp\left({x^2+y^2 \over x^2+y^2+xy^2}\right)
$$
etc.

Comment: This is more elegant than the answer I posted. After the first equality you immediately get $e^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then for $|x|<\epsilon$:
$$
(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+\epsilon y^2+\epsilon x^2}} \leq
(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+x y^2}} \leq
(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-\epsilon y^2-\epsilon y^x}}.
$$
Since 
$$
(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-\epsilon y^2-\epsilon y^x}}=
\Big((1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)}} 
\rightarrow e^{\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)}} \text{ as }(x,y)\rightarrow 0
$$
and
$$
(1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+\epsilon y^2+\epsilon y^x}}=
\Big((1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)}} 
\rightarrow e^{\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)}} \text{ as }(x,y)\rightarrow 0
$$
it follows that 
$$ e^{\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)}} \leq \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow 0} (1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+x y^2}} \leq e^{\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)}}.$$
The above is true for all $\epsilon>0$. Therefore we must have 
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow 0} (1+x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+x y^2}} = e^1 = e.$$